# Memory leak in Kotlin companion objects?

Tags: memory-leaks, kotlin, kotlin-companion

I'm using Kotlin for Android development. Interesting question. In Java saving Context in static field is a memory leak. But if I'm storing context in Kotlin companion object, Android Studio doesn't say that it's a memory leak. It's means that in Java bytecode conpanion object is not a static code? 
For example:

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContext = applicationContext
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var appContext: Context
    }
}
```

Here is no memory leak? Thanks for answers :)

Comment: If you're concerned about a leak you can always use a [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), which will prevent object from being garbage collected untill all 
"strong" references are cleared first.

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does in fact store a `Context` in a static way, it's just that lint can't pick it up and warn you for some reason.

In this specific case, however, you're not really at risk of creating a memory leak. You're storing your `Application` object itself statically, which will be alive for the entirety of your application's life - just like static variables. You'd be in trouble if this was some other, shorter lived `Context`, but the application `Context` should be fine.

For reference about whether it's safe to do this:

- [Is it safe to save the app context to a static variable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10258507/4465208)
- [Is it a bad practice to hold application Context instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20301989/4465208)

Comment: Thanks for answers!

Comment: "Note that, even though the members of companion objects look like static members in other languages, at runtime those are still instance members of real objects" - From the docs at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

So if you do store context behind companion object, under the hood, it's a garbage collectible instance variable.

Comment: Well, yes, but the companion object instance that it belongs to _is_ stored statically.